# Disable Telegram group notifications except from admin

Tags: telegram

I'm part of a large telegram group (say 1000 members).
I don't want to receive notifications for each message. So I've turned off notifications for this group.
But I want to receive notifications for messages posted by admin (or a specific person) only.
Is there an easy way to do this in Android app?